# Yellow on the control flow - No Color within the data flow; What's going on?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

As the question suggests, I'm staring at a transformation that has several control flow elements, many of which are data flows.

Currently, one of the data flow objects within the control flow tab is lit up yellow. When I open that Data Flow object by double click or selecting the "Data Flow" tab, there are no boxes lit up in any color.

This would lead me to believe it's validating, perhaps?

Is there any way to tell what it's doing, and any steps to help make this process faster?

**Edit:

I took a look at the execution, and it looks like it's stuck in the Pre-Execute stage around 50%. Is there any optimization to be done for this stage.

Screenshot of the dataflow that isn't running. (This was taken while the control flow shows this data flow task as yellow)

[image]

Comment: What is your data flow doing? Do you have lookups in your package? If so, the package is most likely in the process of caching the data. How much data? *All* the data so if you merely selected a table name as the lookup or the equivalent `SELECT *` from said table, all that data has to stream across the network to the SSIS engine before it begins processing. If you really want to know, turn on logging in your package.

Comment: It looks like it's stuck in the pre-execute stage. What types of tasks are performed during this stage? I'll try adding some logging and perhaps profiling to try to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Any chance you can pop a screenshot of what the data flow looks like? It'd be helpful to get a visual on what the DF should be doing.

Comment: Added a screenshot. I'm guessing the next step will be to take each of these chunks and put them into their own data flow task to isolate the problem.

Comment: I'd agree with that. Despite what the import/export wizard does, I've never been a fan of having unrelated routes in a data flow-if they don't ever meet up, they go into separate DFs.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance billinkc, definitely put me on the right path. Answer posted below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke out each of these chunks into their own DF. One of these DFs was continuing to get stuck on the Pre-Execute stage. I ran the query for that OLE DB Source and found a long running query due to some dropped indexes. Replaced the index, and the transform stopped hanging.

Answer (score 1):

When you go into the configuration properties of your package and choose 'debugging properties' is it set to run in 'optimized' mode?  If so it will be yellow and then turn green/red when done.  You need to make sure 'run in optimized' is off and 'interactive mode' is true.

Comment: A good thought, but both "RunInOptomizedMode" is set to False and "InteractiveMode" is set to True.

Comment: does it ever turn green/red or hang as yellow?

Comment: It's hanging as yellow. I edited the question, it looks like it's hanging in the Pre-Execute stage.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is to identify *why* it is yellow, view the Error List window and click on Warnings to make them visible if you need to. This should at least confirm if it is just validation, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar problem with a data flow in a SSIS package. No matter how many rows it had to transfer, after it copied all rows, the task remained yellow and there was no data in the destination table (MS SQL Server 2012). I could work-around the problem by dropping the destination table and issue CREATE TABLE/CREATE INDEX again.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution (to those like me who come across this question in the future) is to ensure that the component is not using an internal transaction.

I had this happen (all tasks within data flow green, but showing on the control flow as yellow) this morning with a package doing a bulk update.  The component I was using had a checkbox to turn on an internal transaction, which was waiting for a response from SQL Server before allowing the data flow to complete.

Look for a checkbox to turn off internal transactions or table locks, and rerun without that.